# Simpler proof for the convergence of $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(x)}{1-x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I've been able to prove the convergence of the integral by proving the convergence $\int_0^1 \left|\frac{\ln(x)}{1-x}\right|dx$ using the comparison test. This I did dividing the integral first into $\int_0^\frac{1}{9}\left| \frac{\ln(x)}{1-x}\right|dx$ and comparing it to $\ln(x)^2$ in $[0,\frac{1}{9}]$, and second for $\int_\frac{1}{9}^1 \left|\frac{\ln(x)}{1-x}\right|dx$, for which I showed that  $\left|\frac{\ln(x)}{1-x}\right|$ is continuous in  $\left[\frac{1}{9},1\right)$ and bounded in $\left[\frac{1}{9},1\right]$, which implies $\int_\frac{1}{9}^1 \left|\frac{\ln(x)}{1-x}\right|dx$ converges.

Does anyone know a simpler way to tackle the problem?

Comment: I'll let you flesh out this: combine $\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\ln x}{1-x}=-1$ with the $\frac{\ln x}{1-x}\stackrel{x\to0^+}{\to}\ln x$, together with$$-\int_0^\epsilon\ln xdx=\int_{\exp(-\epsilon)}^\infty ye^{-y}dy<\int_0^\infty ye^{-y}dy=1$$for $0<\epsilon\ll1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more or less simple approach: substitute $\;t=\log x\implies x=e^t\implies dx=e^tdt\;$ , so

$$\int_0^1\frac{\log x}{1-x}dx=\left.\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{e^t}{1-e^t}\cdot t\,dt\stackrel{\text{by parts:} u=t,\,v'=\frac{e^t}{1-e^t}}=\overbrace{-t\log(1-e^t)}^{=0}\right|_{\infty}^0+\int_{-\infty}^0\log(1-e^t)dt=$$

$$=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{e^{nt}}n=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}=-\zeta(2)=-\frac{\pi^2}6$$

It is a nice exercise to formally justify the steps above: why from line 1 to line 2 we can interchange the integral and sum signs ( remember the convergence radius of the Maclaurin series of $\;\log(1-x)\;$), why after the second equality sign in the first line we get that the first term equals zero, etc.

Comment: You might as well just use $y:=1-x$ to write the integral as $-\int_0^1(1+y/2+\cdots)dy=-\zeta(2)$; then we only need to justify a sum/integral exchange.

Comment: @J.G. That is not so clear to me, as the integral's limits remain zero and one...and perhaps seeing it as I posed it we can resource to power series (withou measure theory, Lebesgue theorems and etc.) to justify the exchange of integral and sum...

Comment: Long time no see ! One more elegant solution fro you,, *mon ami* !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Mon cher ami: I'm glad to see you're around ! Thank you for your words and have an excellent 2022.

Comment: Thanks Antonio!!! Is this a good way to formalize what's left? For the first limit to $-\infty$ when can write it as $\frac{\ln(1-e^t)}{\frac{1}{t}}$ and use L'Hopital's rule. And since the Maclaurin series of $\ln(1-x)$ is convergent for $1<|x|$ and $e^t \leq 1$ in $[-\infty,0]$, we can replace $\ln(1-x)$ with the series and then distribute the integral over the sum.

Comment: @MiguelKalinowski Yes, that's correct. I'd only stress that $\;e^t<1\;$in $\;(-\infty,0)\;$ . No need to include the right extreme point.

Answer (score 3):

Note that

$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{x-1}dx
= \int_0^1\frac{2\ln x}{x-1}dx-\int_0^1  \frac{\ln x }{x-1} \overset{x\to x^2}{dx}
= -2\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{x+1}dx  $$

Thus

\begin{align}
0\lt\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{x-1}dx
=&-2\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{x+1}dx
\lt -2\int_0^1 \ln x\ dx=2
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Substituting $x=e^{-t}$ gives
$$
\int_0^1 {\frac{{\log x}}{{1 - x}}dx}  =  - \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{t}{{e^t  - 1}}dt} .
$$
The intgeral clearly converges at $t=+\infty$. To check the convergence near $t=0$, note that
$$
e^t  - 1 = t + \frac{{t^2 }}{2} +  \cdots  > t \Longrightarrow 0 < \frac{t}{{e^t  - 1}} < 1
$$
for any $t>0$.

Answer (score -1):

Define,
\begin{align*}
f: \left]0,1\right[&\longrightarrow \mathbb{R},\\x&\longmapsto \frac{\ln x}{1-x}
\end{align*}

By definition,  if $f$ is  absolutely integrable over  $]0,1[$ so $f$ must be integrable over  the same interval, that is
$$\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|\, {\rm d}x<+\infty \implies \int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,{\rm d}x<+\infty$$

Then, $f$ is absolutely integrable over  $]0,1[$ if for all  $0<\varepsilon<1$ we have
$$\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\varepsilon}|f(x)|\, {\rm d}x}_{I_{2};\text{near}0^{+}}+\underbrace{\int_{\varepsilon}^{1}|f(x)|\, {\rm d}x}_{I_{2};\text{near}1^{-}}$$ they are convergent integrals.

Let's do it,

- $I_{1}$ converges by limit comparison test because $\displaystyle   \left|\frac{\ln x}{1-x}\right| \underset{0^{+}}{\sim }\left|\ln x\right| $ and $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\varepsilon}|\ln x|\, {\rm d}x$ converges.
- $I_{2}$ converges by limit comparison test because $\displaystyle \left|\frac{\ln x}{1-x}\right|\underset{1^{-}}{\sim} \left|-\frac{1-x}{1-x} \right|$ and $\displaystyle \int_{\varepsilon}^{1}\left|-\frac{1-x}{1-x}\right|\,{\rm d}x$ converges.

Therefore, $f$ is absolutely integrable over $]0,1[$ and then $f$ is integrable over the same interval, that is, we have
$$\int_{0}^{1}\left| \frac{\ln x}{1-x}\right|{\rm d}x<+\infty \implies \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln x}{1-x}\, {\rm d}x<+\infty.$$

Now, over $]0,1[$ we have $x\mapsto \ln x$  is non-positive and $x\mapsto \frac{1}{1-x}$ is non-negative. Then for all $x$ in the open interval $]0,1[$ we have  $\left|f(x)\right|=-f(x)$. Hence using that we have $$ \int_{0}^{1}\left| \frac{\log x}{1-x}\right|{\rm d}x=-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln x}{1-x}\, {\rm d}x=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln x}{x-1}\, {\rm d}x=\zeta(2).$$

Comment: Your answer overall is unclear, and further, the equation
$$\int_0^1\frac{\log x}{1-x}\mathrm dx=\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)$$
Is utter nonsense.

Comment: @K.defaoite I don't know which part is unclear. The mapping $f: x\mapsto \frac{\log x}{1-x}$ is continuous on $]0,1[$ and the improper integral has problem near $0^{+}$ and $1^{-}$ but $f\underset{0^{+}}{\sim} \log x$ and $f\underset{1^{-}}{\sim }-1$. Hence not problem because both mapping are integrable on $]0,1[$ and of course $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log x}{1-x}{\rm d}x={\rm Li}_{2}(1-x)$ does not make sense because it's a typo. I corrected.

Comment: @user1027216 The problem is that getting into the solution the function $\;Li_2\;$ doesn't help much to make things easier.. This is at least as harder as the original question so the problem hasn't really been solved for the OP...apparently.

Comment: Hi @DonAntonio I'm sorry, I do not understand the downvote, yet.  The OP is asking about the convergence of $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}\left|\frac{\log x}{1-x}\right|{\rm d}x$ but I showed  that the improper integral converge. The rest was a comment and I am according that find the closed form it is not easy. I hope it's clear now. Thank you for your nice solution.

Comment: @user1027216 I almost never downvote solutions, even if they're completey wrong...and yours isn't, of course. The proof of convergence, in the first part of your answer, uses several not-so-clear things that seem to be equivalences under limits...how does this give convergence isn't completely clear imo.

Comment: Hi @DonAntonio I have re-written my solution to make it more clear, can you please give me your feedback on it? Thank you very much in advance for your time.